# Inserting now() from vb6 into mysql

Tags: mysql, database, datetime, vb6

Sorry for my english.

When I insert now() from vb6 into mysql(it's a datetime type), only zeros are shown(0000-00-00 00:00:00 like this). How can I make them show normally?

When I change the datetime type into text it shows normally, but i can't work with it.

Here's how I insert

```
oSql = "INSERT INTO rendeles(ID_Vevo,Datum,VCime,ID_Alkalmazott) VALUES (" & _
cmbVasarlo.ItemData(cmbVasarlo.ListIndex) & ", '" & Now() & "', '" & _ 
oRs1!Cim & "', " & logged_user_id & ")"

Set oRs = oConn.Execute(oSql)
```

Comment: Doesnt MYSql require dates as `YYYY-MM-DD`?  Now() wont return that.

Comment: Yes, but i need the time to be stored also. I can store it as text with the time included, but later can't put it into a combo box as a Date. I hope this makes sense :(.

Comment: you still need to format the output from NOW() to what mysql requires - `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` for date and time. thats not what Now() returns.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this (I am real rusty on my VB6)

```
Dim sqlDate As String
sqlDate = Format$(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")

...
cmbVasarlo.ItemData(cmbVasarlo.ListIndex) & ", '" & sqlDate  & "', '" & _ 
oRs1!Cim & "', " & logged_user_id & ")"
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed. And btw Now() returns yyyy/mm/dd and now yyyy-mm-dd, this was the problem I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

Format VB6's NOW() function to MYSQL's used format

```
Format$(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

OR

Just use Now() function of MYSQL instead of VB6's

```
oSql = "INSERT INTO rendeles(ID_Vevo,Datum,VCime,ID_Alkalmazott) VALUES (" & _
cmbVasarlo.ItemData(cmbVasarlo.ListIndex) & ", now(), '" & _ 
oRs1!Cim & "', " & logged_user_id & ")"
```